# Dynamic calendar in Google Sheets - how to query in items from a list

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a calendar in sheets where you can change the heading (say from 1/1/2021 to 2/1/2021) and all the events for that month auto-populate from a list in another sheet. I just can't get it to work! The ideal would be stacked items like this: (all are in the same day)

- Event 1
- Event 2
- ...
- Event N

The query that DOESN'T work is here:

> =QUERY(
> {
> Events!A:A&" - "&
> Events!C:C&" - "&
> Events!E:E,
> Events!I:I
> },
> "select Col1
> where Col2 = date '"&text(($A$1+C4-1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"
> )

This fails with "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: 984."
My intent is to concatenate columns A, C, and E to Col1 and I to Col2 (date column)

Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NAcLwRDSkLzQcdk0dqQISm1L_TSfnTnWhCTOXrZU440/edit#gid=0) The ideally formatted solution is in green, the broken formula is in pink.

Anyone have a solution for this? Appreciate the help!

Adding in the final solution courtesy of Player0:

> =IFERROR(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Events!A:A&" - "&Events!C:C&" - "&Events!E:E&char(10), Events!I:I},
> "select Col1 where Col2 = date '"&TEXT(($A$1+B4-1), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0 ))),"")

Added a char(10) to create a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Events!A:A&" - "&Events!C:C&" - "&Events!E:E, Events!I:I}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = date '"&TEXT(($A$1+C4-1), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'" ))
```

see:

#### https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471

Comment: Thank you @player0! I made a small modification to get it to stack but that worked great!

Comment: Here is the finished dynamic calendar: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NAcLwRDSkLzQcdk0dqQISm1L_TSfnTnWhCTOXrZU440/edit#gid=0